# Installing pyqt5 with MinGW and sip. Where is the "make" command?

Tags: c++, windows, mingw, pyqt5

I want to use pyqt5 with python. I have found instructions
Using sip-4.17/sip-4.17/doc/html/installation.html#downloading.  I have installed MinGW. The instructions for build read: 
"Building
The next step is to build SIP by running your platform’s make command. For example:
make
The final step is to install SIP by running the following command:

make install
(Depending on your system you may require root or administrator privileges.)

This will install the various SIP components."

I am a complete newbie at this particular thing.  I don't see "make" as a file in the MinGW directory.  Should I use bin/mingw32-make.exe with no object listed? What about make install?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

make is in the msys subdirectory. msys should be a subdir of MinGW. If not you need to install [MSYS](http://www.mingw.org/wiki/msys). This [post](http://www.stringcat.com/company_blog/2015/12/07/compiling-openssl-on-windows-mingw32/) might help.